# Creating a C++ application with Python code included

Tags: python, c++, cmake

I'm trying to create a "helloworld" app in C++, with an integrated Python code. I include Python.h, and it is seen by static analyzer fine. As I build my code I get `undefined reference to '_imp__Py_Initialize'`, so make failed

I'm running Windows7-x64 with Python3.5-x32, MinGW-x64, CLion to write code. None of guides i found show the complete step-by-step solutions. If I have to re-install some specific versions of software, I need to know - what to do...

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(sample)
find_package(PythonLibs 3.5 REQUIRED)
find_package(PythonInterp 3.5 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
add_executable(sample main.cpp)
```

main.cpp

```c
#include <Python.h>
int main() {
  Py_Initialize();
  PyRun_SimpleString("print('hello, python')");
  Py_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

So the subject raises, i have an undefined reference. As i add `target_link_libraries(${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})` to my `CMakeLists.txt` i get another exception:

```
Cannot specify link libraries for target
"C:/Users/...../Python35-32/python35.dll"
which is not built by this target.
```

Please provide me some more ideas, what to do with this, if you don't mind.

Comment: `target_link_libraries(${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})` takes the *target* as first parameter. Your target is `sample`, so try with `target_link_libraries(sample ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})`

Comment: ```
Cannot specify link libraries for target "sample" which is not built by this project
```

Comment: Did you put that line before or after the `add_executable`?

Comment: It somehow works if i put it after. BUT WHY? can you, please post your answer as an actual answer so i can vote for it, and mark as a solution?

Comment: See if the answer also covers the"why" part ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`target_link_libraries` takes the **target** as first parameter. 
From the documentation of [`target_link_libraries`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_link_libraries.html):

> The named `target` must have been created in the current directory by
>   a command such as `add_executable()` or `add_library()`. The remaining
>   arguments specify library names or flags.

Your target is `sample`, not because of the `project(sample)` at the beginning, but because of `add_executable(sample main.cpp)`, so add

```
`target_link_libraries(sample ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})`
```

**after** the `add_executable` line.